# Toad - NamedSQL Backup

Tags: oracle, toad

In Toad, SQL statements can be saved as Named SQL. How can I take backup of  named SQL statements and restore when Toad crashes or use in another PC or computer.

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know which version you have. By me is in:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Dell\Toad for Oracle\12.9\User Files\SavedSQL.xml
```

See all *.XML files in the same directory. There are connections, code templates and more

Comment: You can also perform a full export of all configuration files by using the Copy User Settings window available from the Utilities menu.

Comment: Also, older versions of Toad used SavedSQL.dat as the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, appreciated and thanks @MichaelS. for the comment.

Comment: You're welcome. I didn't want to spam with additional comments yesterday, but I remembered that the SQL Recall dock panel has buttons for import/export of your SQL. If you don't see the buttons expand the width of the panel or click the little drop arrow to the right of the toolbar to see buttons that cannot fit given its width.

Comment: @MichaelS. Yes I did see those options for Export and Import. Thanks again.